# In flask-jwt-extended how to set a custom token expiry time?

Tags: flask-jwt-extended

In [flask-jwt-entended](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/#) package how can we set a custom token expiry time say for example 72 hours? I couldn't find any annotation of examples in the documentation link shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options/#JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES if you want to change it globally, or https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/#flask_jwt_extended.create_access_token if you want to change it dynamically or only for some tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the token expiration time by passing 'expires_delta' parameter to the 'create_access_token' function:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token
from flask_login import current_user

expires = timedelta(days=3)
token = create_access_token(identity=str(current_user.id), expires_delta=expires)
```